# "Error executing bcdedit.exe command" when trying to install via wubi

Tags: windows, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I install Ubuntu or Wubi on a dynamic disk? (“The request isn't supported” from bcdedit.exe)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179215/why-cant-i-install-ubuntu-or-wubi-on-a-dynamic-disk-the-request-isnt-suppor)

> An error occurred:
>
> Error executing command command=C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit.exe /set
>   {63bc2fe2-24a2-11e1-a588-b3529b3c61fc} device partition=L: retval=1
>   stderr=An error has occurred setting the element data. The request is
>   not supported.
>
> stdout=
>
> For more information, please see the log file:
>   c:\users\account\appdata\local\temp\wubi-12.04-rev266.log

Any idea how to work-around this error?  It appears with 0s left on installation time.  Thanks in advance.